# Binding primitives to a controller works only for the constructor

Tags: laravel

I bound a primitive value to a class.

```php
$this->app->when('App\Http\Controllers\TestController')
            ->needs('$numPages')
            ->give(1000);
```

But this value is injected only into the class's constructor and not into other methods.

```php
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct($numPages = 0)
    {
        // $numPages = 1000  WORKS
    }

    public function index($numPages = 0)
    {
        // $numPages = 0  DOESNT WORK
    }
}
```

But when I bind a regular class, its instance is injected in all methods. Is it intended behavior?

Comment: I think you need to set the `numPages` property in your `TestController` constructor and then access it as a property from any of the class methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is likely intended as your `TestController::index` params should be provided by the route. So a route like `/testcontroller/index/{numPages}` could provide the `$numPages` value of 4 when `/testcontroller/index/4` is hit.

If it was possible to inject that via DI, you may end up with bugs where you're expecting the value to come from the route, but a different value is being injected.